# Match and Count the Data Matrix in R

Tags: r, perl, count, match

The dataset looks like this:

```
 Gene SampleName
gene1    sample1
gene1    sample2
gene1    sample3
gene2    sample2
gene2    sample3
gene2    sample4
gene3    sample1
gene3    sample5
```

My goal is to make a data matrix like this:

```
       gene1 gene2 gene3
gene1      -     2     1
gene2      -     -     0
gene3      -     -     -
```

`gene1` vs `gene2` is `2` because they share the same samples `sample2` and `sample3`. `gene1` vs `gene3` is 1 because they only share one same sample - `sample1`.

My question is how can I achieve this goal in R or Perl? The actual data set is much larger. I highly appreciate your help.

---

Here's the `dput(df)` output for R:

```
df <- structure(list(Gene = c("gene1", "gene1", "gene1", "gene2", "gene2", 
"gene2", "gene3", "gene3"), SampleName = c("sample1", "sample2", 
"sample3", "sample2", "sample3", "sample4", "sample1", "sample5"
)), .Names = c("Gene", "SampleName"), row.names = c(NA, -8L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hello sgibb, thank you very much for making the format for me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can look at the `crossprod` (or `tcrossprod`) function along with `table`:

```
out <- tcrossprod(table(df))
out
#        Gene
# Gene    gene1 gene2 gene3
#   gene1     3     2     1
#   gene2     2     3     0
#   gene3     1     0     2
```

Drop the diagonal and the lower-triangle to get the exact output you show.

```
diag(out) <- NA
out[lower.tri(out)] <- NA
print.table(out)  ## print.table deals with NAs differently
#        Gene
# Gene    gene1 gene2 gene3
#   gene1           2     1
#   gene2                 0
#   gene3
```

Comment: Nice.  I didn't know about `tcrossprod` and rarely see anyone use `crossprod`, myself included.

Comment: @Ananda, I am sorry to bother you again. This code works perfect for the example. When I trying to use table(df) to the larger dataset, the SampleName is not unique, resulting in the count is not accurate. Do you have any idea which part I did was wrong.

Comment: @user3637642, can you recreate it with a smaller dataset, update your question, and ping me here in the comments? It's hard to say otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -lane'
  $s{$F[0]}++ or push @k, $F[0];
  $h{$F[1]}{$F[0]} = 1;
END {
  $, = "\t";
  print "", @k;
  for $c (@k) {
    print $c, map {
      $u = $_;      
      ($c eq $u) ? "-" : scalar grep $_->{$c} && $_->{$u}, values %h;
    } @k;
  }
}
' file
```

output

```
        gene1   gene2   gene3
gene1   -       2       1
gene2   2       -       0
gene3   1       0       -
```

Comment: that looks quite complicated compared to @Ananda's R answer

Comment: @beginneR, I'm sure there are things that look complicated in R too, but simpler in other languages.

Comment: @beginneR yes, it does; it is completely another language (perl lacks some built-ins which can be found in R).

Comment: of course you are both right (and i have no clue of perl). just noticed the difference in this particular example. i didnt mean to say R > Perl